# undefined local variable or method `acts_as_taggable' in gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, rubygems, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm working on converting a plugin to a gem. In one of the models I'm using acts_as_taggable_on, and it looks like this

```
class BlogPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable
  ....
end
```

However, I get this error when I run it:

```
 undefined local variable or method `acts_as_taggable' for #<Class:0x000000060799b8>
```

and the stack trace looks like this:

```
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/base.rb:1082:in `method_missing'
test_gem (0.1.0) app/models/blog_post.rb:28:in `<class:BlogPost>'
test_gem (0.1.0) app/models/blog_post.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
```

The acts_as_taggable gem is included in my gemspec file and is installed on the system.

```
gem install acts-as-taggable-on
Successfully installed acts-as-taggable-on-2.1.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for acts-as-taggable-on-2.1.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for acts-as-taggable-on-2.1.1...
```

I have no idea what could be wrong - please help me out

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?  I'm running in the same issue?

Answer (score 23):

I had the same issue. I restarted my server and it worked fine after

Comment: I'd to restart rails console. reload! method didn't worked.

Answer (score 4):

none of above answers works for me, what I did was put :

```
 require 'acts-as-taggable-on'
```

in the beginning the model where I'm using the gem :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you put the following in you Gemfile:

```
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~>2.1.0'
```

then

```
bundle install
```